# Looking for a short story about a man forced to shelter and serve a man of authority

Tags: story-identification

I have been searching for a short story I read years ago about a man who quarters a cruel person of authority (general? king? dictator?). The cruel person forces the man quartering him to serve him every minute of the day. Everything he demanded had to be done. It went this way for years. As the cruel man was dying (of an illness?), he demanded the peasant pledge him his loyalty. When the cruel man died, the peasant simply uttered, "never" (or something similar).

I'm thinking the story was by Orwell, Heinlein, or Wells, because I was reading their work at the time, but no search I do turns anything up. Can anyone help?

Comment: By quartering do you mean 'providing lodgings or housing for' ? Assuming that's the intent, what made the story sci-fi or fantasy? About when did you read it and/or might it have been published? Was it YA ?

Comment: No, by quartering I mean "provide lodging for". And I'm almost certain it was by a scifi author in some collection...

Comment: I saw the title and assumed "quartering" meant "[cutting into four pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanged,_drawn_and_quartered)".  Maybe a different word would be better.

Comment: @NateEldredge, ok, I changed it. It's funny to me how people receive very different connotations; the other definition of quartering (as in "drawn and quartered") never even occurred to me!

Comment: Don't understand the 'No' response since I asked if you meant 'provide lodging'. How about when read/published and what's sci-fi or fantasy about it.

Comment: @Stan, I explained the "no": It means "providing lodging", *not* drawing-and-quartering. I also said in the question that it was years ago, and I thought it appropriate to post here, because it was most likely a fantasy/sci-fi author (specifically, likely a writer who wrote famously about dystopian futures), just because that's what I was seeking and reading at the time (years ago). It originally could have been published decades ago, but I'm not sure. I'm really not sure about anything except the story line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no discernible science fiction or fantasy content

Comment: @Richard, it was likely part of a sci-fi/fantasy collection/anthology. Where would be appropriate to ask this question? It would be great if the official policy was that for a sincere question to be marked as off-topic, you have to provide a suggestion of an alternative location to ask the question.

Comment: @BlueBomber - There are a variety of other places you can ask non-sci-fi story ident questions; http://www.loganberrybooks.com/stumpthebookseller/ would probably be a good start. The rec.arts.written newsgroup can often be helpful too.

Comment: @Stan: Yeah, I initially posted a comment after yours that said I assumed the same thing as Nate Eldredge. Must've deleted it.